# When change marker position on click, info window not remove

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I change the marker position on click the map info window of last position did not remove. My code is following. For example, when I click on google map marker position is changed `w-r-t` to that lat and long. And info window shows that `lat`, `long`. And after that when I change again the position of marker and open the info window it shows the `lat`, `long`. And when I click on close window it shows last info window behind it. And then I need to close that window. How can I fix it?

```
var marker2 = "";
function customMap(ulat,ulong,blat,blong) 
{
      //console.log(params);
      var map_div = "map-canvas";
      // var map_div = params.mapDiv;

      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(ulat, ulong);
      var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(blat,blong);
      var loc_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.8212783,90.4278342);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: myLatlng1
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById( map_div ), mapOptions);


      var content_data = "<center>User</center>";
      var content_data3 = "<center>Location</center>";
      var content_data2 = "<div><strong>Location</strong><br>Lat:&nbsp;"+blat+"<br>Long:&nbsp;"+blong+"<br>Click on Map to change location<br><a class='del_icon' onclick='DeleteMarker();'>Delete Location</a></div>";
     // show full map button 
     map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(
     FullScreenControl(map));

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        icon: this_domain_cp+"/mvc/images/user_map_icon.png",
        //title: 'User'
      });
      attachMessage(marker, content_data);

      marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng1,
        map: map,
        //title: 'building'
      });
      attachMessage(marker2, content_data2);

      marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: loc_latlng,
        map: map,
        icon: this_domain_cp+"/mvc/images/loc_icon.png",
        title: 'Location'
      });
      attachMessage(marker3, content_data3);

    //update lat long of building (red marker)
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {

        var blat = event.latLng.lat();
        var blong = event.latLng.lng();

        var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(blat, blong);
        var newloc = marker2.setPosition(myLatlng1);

        var content_data2 = "<div><strong>Location</strong><br>Lat:&nbsp;"+blat+"<br>Long:&nbsp;"+blong+"<br>Click on Map to change location<br><a class='del_icon' onclick='DeleteMarker();'>Delete Location</a></div>";
        attachMessage(marker2, content_data2);
        infowindow.close();

        $('#building_latitude').val(blat);
        $('#building_longitude').val(blong);


    });

}

    function attachMessage(marker, content_data) {
        //    var message = 'This is my';
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: content_data
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
            infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
        });

    }


    function DeleteMarker(id) {
        marker2.setMap(null);
        $('#building_latitude').val(0);
        $('#building_latitude').attr("disabled","disabled");
        $('#building_longitude').attr("disabled","disabled");
        $('#building_longitude').val(0);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including any required HTML/CSS.

Comment: Do you only ever want one infowindow open?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to keep a reference to the infowindow and close it if you run your attachMessage function again on the same infowindow:

```
function attachMessage(marker, content_data) {
    //    var message = 'This is my';
    if (marker.infowindow) {
       marker.infowwindow.close();
    }
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: content_data
    });
    marker.infowindow = infowindow;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
    });

}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/99tLu47j/)

If you only ever want one infowindow open, create one in the global context and reuse that for any marker that is clicked.